# Question about tf | problem with ar_pose reverse

Tags: ar-pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I successfully run [ar_pose](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_pose) with tracking a single marker option. I also tried to run option: tracking the camera position (reverse), everything looks good, but I don't get image...

My topics exists but rviz says something different.

Please check this screen: http://snag.gy/OhN45.jpg

rostopic seems to be ok:

```
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws/src/ar_tools/ar_pose/launch$ rostopic list 
/ar_pose_marker
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_color
/camera/image_color/compressed
/camera/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_color/theora
/camera/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_mono
/camera/image_mono/compressed
/camera/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_mono/compressedDepth
/camera/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_mono/theora
/camera/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_proc_debayer/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_proc_debayer/parameter_updates
/camera/image_proc_rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_proc_rectify_color/parameter_updates
/camera/image_proc_rectify_mono/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_proc_rectify_mono/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect
/camera/image_rect/compressed
/camera/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect/theora
/camera/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect_color
/camera/image_rect_color/compressed
/camera/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/camera/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_rect_color/theora
/camera/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/clicked_point
/initialpose
/move_base_simple/goal
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
/visualization_marker
/visualization_marker_array
```

I get launch file from [this repository](https://github.com/xqms/ar_tools/blob/catkin/ar_pose/launch/ar_pose_reverse.launch)

my launch looks:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find ar_pose)/launch/live_reverse.rviz"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_marker" 
    args="0 1 1 -1.57 3.14 -1.57 world ar_marker 10" />
  <node ns="camera" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc"/>
  <node ns="camera" pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_camera_node" name="uvc_camera_node"
    output="screen">
    <param name="width" type="int" value="320" />
    <param name="height" type="int" value="240" />
    <param name="fps" type="int" value="30" />
    <param name="frame" type="string" value="camera" />
    <param name="device" type="string" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="camera_info_url" type="string"
      value="file://$(find ar_pose)/camera_calibration_rev.yaml" />
  </node>
  <node name="ar_pose" pkg="ar_pose" type="ar_single" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="marker_pattern" type="string" value="data/4x4/4x4_19.patt"/>
    <param name="marker_width" type="double" value="152.4"/>
    <param name="marker_center_x" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="marker_center_y" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
    <param name="use_history" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <param name="reverse_transform" type="bool" value="true"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Where did I make a mistake?
please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198329/question-about-tf-%7C-problem-with-ar_pose-reverse/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-11-26**:
The camera image does not depend on ar_pose. Try running only the camera related nodes and see if it's solved.

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-11-26**:
When I use tracking a single marker option camera works excellent. http://snag.gy/WiqGT.jpg
When I use reverse option something is broken. http://snag.gy/aHn1s.jpg

launch files compared: http://www.diffnow.com/?report=0c3yj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that your launchfile is setting up a TF between world and camera, and the marker package is also trying to set up a TF between the marker and the camera, and camera cannot have two TF parents.

Remove that static tf publisher from the launchfile and the problem should be solved.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0